# How does the step transition in this origami construction occur?

Tags: origami

In *Tanteidan Convention Book 13*, "Nautilus" (pp.186-197), I am unable to physically realise the fold that takes diagram 15 to diagram 16:

[image: diagrams for steps 15 and 16]

How does this step "manifest" on the paper? I end up with the coloured portion covering the hump in a way that does not obviously transition into diagram 16.

Comment: You need to include a picture or something from that book. The second that link on drive stops working this question becomes harder to read and understand.

Comment: @Matt, did the screencaps/edit, given that the link was to a pirated PDF of the book.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to pull out the paper as far as the vertical split visible in step 15. At the same time it will "wrap around" to show the other side of the paper.

You could also look at it like this: if in step 15 you completely unfold the white part, you will see a small square with a crease pattern such as for the bird base. Now, along the precreased lines, collapse one diagonal half of the square into a half of the bird base, and the other half of the square leave folded in two. This produces your step 16.